# How to stop AttributeGraph being generated from Picker

Tags: macos, swiftui

I understand the cause here, but cannot find a straightforward solution.  Can anyone see a simple solution that I am just not seeing ?

The cascade of AttributeGraph errors occurs when the focus is on one TextField and the picker is changed to the alternate field.  The objective is to have a picker selectively enable certain fields within a form.  This is just a simplistic case to demonstrate the issue.

I understand that removing the ".disable" will prevent the cascade of errors and that a TextField having focus is the root cause.  I have not been able to find a way to remove focus from the TextField when the picker changes.

This on on MacOS 10.15 using Xcode 12.4.  If this does not happen in later versions, then I will just have to live with it since I am stuck on 10.15 due to hardware limitation.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AttributeGraphIssueView: View {
  private var choices = ["Choice 1","Choice 2"]
  @State private var selection:String = "Choice 1"
  @State private var entryForChoice1: String = "Hello"
  @State private var entryForChoice2: String = "World"
    var body: some View {
      Picker( selection: $selection, label: EmptyView() ) {
          ForEach (choices, id:\.self) { entry in
          Text(entry)
        }
      }
      TextField("for choice 1", text: $entryForChoice1)
        .disabled(selection == choices[1])
        .background((selection == choices[1]) ? Color.red: Color.green)
      TextField("for choice 2", text: $entryForChoice2)
        .disabled(selection == choices[0])
        .background((selection == choices[0]) ? Color.red: Color.green)
    }
}
```

So I have arrived at an ugly, but functional solution, which is to not render the TextField rather than disable them.  The code for the TextField becomes

```
      if (selection != choices[1]) {
        TextField("for choice 1", text: $entryForChoice1)
        .foregroundColor((selection == choices[1]) ? Color.red: Color.green)
      }
```

Why ugly?  Because this means that the static form has become dynamic.  Perhaps a personal preference but I prefer fields in a  form to stay put once rendered. I'd prefer a cleaner solution if anyone can see one.

Comment: So, I have a somewhat ugly solution. The messages are suppressed if the TextField is not displayed.  That is, remove the .disable and bracket in an if thus

Comment: Not reproduced with Xcode 13 / macOS 11.6. No warnings generated in console.

Comment: Thanks for checking, good to know and does not surprise me that it has been fixed. As it is only a private application I will move on to the next stage.